# Solve an equation consisting of several incomplete Gamma functions.

Tags: approximation, gamma-function

How should I solve this equation, please. Can the positive solution x be represented precisely by a,b, and c? If not, are there some approximations to solve the problem?

[\begin{array}{l}
\Gamma \left( {n,\frac{x}{{{\varphi _1}}}} \right) + \Gamma \left( {n,\frac{x}{{{\varphi _2}}}} \right) - \Gamma \left( {n,\frac{x}{{{\varphi _3}}}} \right) - \Gamma \left( {n,\frac{x}{{{\varphi _4}}}} \right) = 0;\\
{\varphi _1} = a + b + c;\\
{\varphi _2} = c;\\
{\varphi _3} = a + c;\\
{\varphi _4} = b + c;\\
0 < a \ll b,0 < a \ll c;\\
n \in {Z^ + }n > 50\\
x = ?
\end{array}]